# Why doesnt it output my string variable value completely?

Tags: visual-c++

I have a problem with my program that i could not solve for days. The problem is with my c++ code.

```
    #include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Friend
{
private:
    string name;
    string age;
    string gender;
public:
    Friend(string x, string y, string z)
    {
        x = name;
        y = age;
        z = gender;
    }

    string giveFriendInfo()
    {
        string info = "His name is " + name + " of age " + age + " and gender " + gender;
        return info;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Friend fo("Jonathan", "17", "male");
    cout << fo.giveFriendInfo() << "\n";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to build it in my visual studio 2017 and it builds fine. When i run it tho, this is the output it gave me :

His name is  of age  and gender

Thats all, it didnt output the value of the name, gender and age. I dont understand why? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps it for the exemple Yursi but please avoid for you and for other people variable with with "x, y ,z, a, b, c, d" named value :). Dipstick answer should work anyway :)

Comment: ok ill try to not use the variable x, y and z as parameters. Just running out of names :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Friend(string x, string y, string z)
{
    x = name;
    y = age;
    z = gender;
}
```

Presumably you meant:

```
Friend(string x, string y, string z)
{
    name = x;
    age = y;
    gender = z;
}
```

Comment: Wait, whats the difference tho? Sry i might be forgetting something. Cool that it worked tho.

Comment: In your code you were copying the "null" value of name, age, gender into x, y, z , so x, y ,z would be null and name, age, gender too. In the solution we copy not null value of x, y, z into name, age, gender that's why it work